# Strange noise in audio background

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, noise

I've set up an audio amplifier using TDA7297 and Raspberry Pi's 3.5 mm audio jack.
And I'm using omxd, a daemon for omxplayer, and playing mp4 video files. The audio output has been set to jack.

But the problem is that there's a strange noise in the background of audio. (The recorded audio is http://vocaroo.com/i/s0c0RC3uJE2o and http://vocaroo.com/i/s0Ek3z3ltDSO. One is main audio+noise, the other is just noise with the main audio paused.) This problem occurs when the grounds of both systems (RPi and external audio amplifier) are connected. When disconnecting the grounds, this noise disappears.

But I need the common ground to use logic levels, control audio via MCU, use SPI, etc.

I tried simple RC low-pass, high-pass, band-pass, band-stop, notch, ... filters, but no help!

So, any suggestions !?
What causes this noise !? And how can I eliminate it !?

Comment: Show us a wiring diagram.

Comment: @Trevor This http://circuits.datasheetdir.com/271/TDA7297-circuits.jpg is the schematic for TDA7297 section. The audio from RPi is connected to this.

Comment: I'm more interested in how you wired up the grounds between those and your power supply.

Comment: How about a picture of what your setup looks like, physically? One suggestion is to try connecting the signal ground of the amplifier directly to the signal ground of the audio jack, with no other connections. This sounds like it could be a ground loop...

Comment: @Trevor I use 5 volt supply for RPi, and 12 volt supply for audio amplifier. Then I connect the grounds of both power supplies with a simple wire. Also, I checked using only one power supply (5 volt), but the same problem happens.

Comment: Is there more than one ground connection between then... that is, you say you have the grounds tied together at the power supply, but do you ALSO have signal grounds or shielding grounds between the units.

Comment: @Trevor No there isn't any other grounds. I also remove the ground of the audio jack, connecting only the left audio signal. But no help. I guess the wobbling-like noise is around 2 Hz. But I don't know what it is.

Comment: A daemon is causing strange noises in your audio background, sounds like you need an exorcist

Comment: Well, the raspi's stereo output is a simple PWM which uses the cpu's power supply as voltage reference, so really, any noise on the 3V3 supply will be fed straight into the output!